# I can't change the color of my website anymore

Tags: html, css

I tried to change the color of my website. For example I changed "background-color: #3695F6;" to "background-color: #fff;". but my website background doesn't change. I tried to find a missing 
semicolon but I didn't find any. I also tried to delete parts of the Css/Html code which I didn't fully understand but that changed nothing. After all that failed I tried to change a margin on the website from 40px to 100px and nothing changed. I think my Css isn't properly connected. can someone please help.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  font: 0.9em Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
  line-height:172%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#containercontainer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 30px;

}


/* bovenste kopje ========================================*/
h1.titel {
  color: black;
  font: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}


#titel {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
  width: 5.5%;
  left: 45%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}




/* De Slideshow ========================================*/


.fling-minislide {
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 padding-bottom: 0%; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 position:relative; 
 }
 
.fling-minislide img{ 
 position:absolute; 
 animation:fling-minislide 15s infinite; 
 opacity: 0;  
 size: 100% 100%;
 }

@keyframes fling-minislide {33%{opacity:1;} 60%{opacity:0;}} 
 .fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:0s;}
 .fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:5s;}
 .fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:10s;}

#slideshow {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: center;
  border: solid black 2px;
  width: 55%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 21%;
}

/* Het nieuws blokje ========================================*/

img.nieuws {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p.nieuws {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}

#nieuws {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 78%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Het vragen blokje ========================================*/


#vragen {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1000px;
  left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  top: 300px;
}


p.A{
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

    #pointer {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      background: black;
   margin-left: 30px;
    }
    #pointer:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid white;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    }
    #pointer:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid black;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    }
 
p.vragentop1 {
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-top: -25px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 width: 600px;
  
}

p.vragentext1 {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 600px;
}  






/* hoveren over plaatje in directie//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

 
 .container::after, .row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
 
.column {
float: left;
width: 30%;
margin-bottom: 16px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0 8px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
.column {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
}

.columnL {
float: left;
width: 30%;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
padding: 0 8px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.card {
box-shadow: 6px 7px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
border: solid black 2px;
padding-left: 10px;
}


  /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/


#cbrlogo {
 background: #fff;
 width: 50px;
}

#container {
  width: relative;
  padding: relative;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#containercontainer2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.afbeelding_container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.afbeelding_container .tekst_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  color: #00f;
  font-size: 36px;

}

.schoon {
  clear: both;
}


#overzicht {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.links {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
}

#rechts {
  float: right;
}

#onder {
  clear: both;
}

.breder {
  width: 4000px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #00f;
}

hr {
  margin: 0px 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 10px solid #00f;
  background-color: #fff;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #3695F6;
}

ul.menu {
list-style-type: none;
}

img.menu{
 border: solid black 2px;
}

.menu li {
float:left;
position:relative;
width: 200px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
}

.menu li a {
display: block;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu li a span{
display: block;
padding-top: 10px;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
color: black;
font-size: 18px;
}



.menu li:hover span{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

th {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

td {
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

td.muteren {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}


tbody:before {
    line-height:1em;
    display:block;
}

thead {
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
Body
```

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue or that an external CSS file is not loaded. How is the CSS loaded? externally, any network errors? Your CSS seems to set the body to white in the snippet I made

Answer (score 0):

this problem could be the caching problem try clearing your cache if that doesn't work check how you are linking your css to your HTML file if it's correct you can do the last thing which is add !important to the end of the background color like the example below:

```
background-color:#fff !important;
```